# Passing data into child route when navigating in-app, or using resolver when navigating directly

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have two components, an expense report component and a historical expenses component. The routes look like this:

`expenses/:id` for the `ExpenseReportComponent`, and brings up a view that shows that particular expense report.
`expenses/:id/historical` for the `HistoricalExpensesComponent`, and is a child route for the above. That brings up a view that shows historical expenses for that reports' employee (driven by an employeeID). Note that the employee ID DOES NOT equal the expense ID, the employee ID is derived from the expense ID.

When someone loads `expenses/:id` we fetch data about that expense report, including the candidate ID. when someone loads `expenses/:id/historical`, we have a resolver that automatically fetches the report data, and resolves with the employee ID (which is what the component needs to run).

This brought up the question: how can I avoid this API call in the child resolver when navigating from the parent to the child controller. Obviously because we're in the parent controller, we already have the employeeID that is needed by the child controller, but I didn't know how to pass that data to the navigation.

Turns out the solution was to use state. I set the employeeID on the state as part of the router link from the parent. In the resolver, I check for that state - if it's there, I return it immediately, and if it's not there (someone navigated to the child route directly, or refreshed the page) then we get the api.

I was curious if this is best practice, or if I missed something obvious? I know there are a variety of ways we could make this work (like using a service). The idea for this is that the child component would always get it's data from whatever the route is so that it doesn't need to know anything else, other than "check router resolve data for my content". Is this method prone to some issue that I'm overlooking? It took a good hour to come up with the solution (would have been sooner, but we originally couldn't figure out how to access state in the resolver.)

Code examples:

```
// Routes
    {
        path: 'expenses/:id',
        children: [
            { path: '', component: ExpenseReportComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
            {
                path: 'historical',
                component: HistoricalExpensesComponent,
                resolve: {
                    "candidateId": ExpenseCandidateResolver
                }
            },
        ]
    },
```

```
// Resolver
@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
})
export class ExpenseCandidateResolver implements Resolve<any> {
    constructor(private _http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        const candidate = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras?.state?.candidate;
        // if state exists and has a candidate ID, immiiately resolve with that
        if (candidate) {
            return candidate;
        }
        // otherwise get the candiate via api
        return this._http.get<any>("http://localhost:33333/api/report/" + route.params.id)
        .toPromise()
        .then(data => {
            return data.CandidateID;
        })
        // todo: handle error
    }
}
```

```
<!-- Link to navigate within the parent controller --> 
<a routerLink="historical" [state]="{ candidate: Report.CandidateID }">Historical</a>
```

Comment: I think another approach would be to use [matrix params](https://indepth.dev/posts/1379/angular-router-revealing-some-interesting-facts-and-features#how-to-specify-when-guards-and-resolvers-should-run)(you'll have to scroll down a bit).